# Can't read resources when running methods from dex file

Tags: android, android-resources, dex, dexclassloader

I had a jar file that contains code and resources (`ResourceBundle`).
I've created a simple project in android studio with that jar, compiled it, extracted the `.apk` and copied the `classes.dex` to a second project. Also copied the resources from the extracted .apk to the second project.

From the second project I've loaded a class from the .dex file.
When running a method from that class (from the dex file) that reads a resource it won't find it, it would throw an exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle ...
```

The line that fails:

```
ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("xx.yy.zz.resources.aa", Locale.getDefault());
```

If I just run:

```
ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("xx.yy.zz.resources.aa", Locale.getDefault());
```

from the second project (not from whithin the dex) it will work ok - will get the resource.

Any idea guys?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works, wanted to share:
Instead of using the classes.dex use the .apk for the classloader.
It knows how to read the functions from the dex inside it and get the resources from it.